# power down some but not all DDR on a bus? And I'm thinking of DDR3/3L and DDR2. 

Tags: power, memory, ddr

I'm starting to learn about power managment, and am wondering, can you power off a DDR module on a memory bus while others are still in use? Or does that mangle signal integrity on the bus? I assume it's OK to turn off one full bus while continuing to use another bus, such as dual-channel memory controller?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Most chips don't tolerate their inputs being above their Vcc, as would be in the powered off module.

Your second case can be done, in theory.